# Two Particles with identical temperatures at different points in the atmosphere

Tags: thermodynamics, radioactivity, convection

Quick question with probably a simple answer. For context, I am currently in undergraduate classical mechanics studying potential energy. My question is, if a conservative force is one in which is only a function of position, can radioactivity be a conservative force?

The example I thought of was if we take two identical particles which are undergoing radioactive decay, and we put one in the upper bound regions of the atmosphere, and the other at sea level, can we say that radiation is a function of position? I guess this also poses the question, can atmospheric pressure/temperature affect radioactivity?

Feel free to slaughter my logic/understanding. Thanks :)

Comment: I believe all four fundamental forces are conservative. One of them, the weak interaction, underlies some forms of radioactivity.

Comment: All four fundamental interactions are conservative as we can write the Hamiltonian (basically the energy potential) that we use to derive them.

Comment: It is unclear what atmosphere has to do with radioactivity in your question. Of course forces due to friction with atmosphere or that produce heat are not conservative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding radioactivity: The transition probability per unit time for a decay transition is approximated by Fermi's Golden Rule:

$$ \Gamma = \frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|M|^2\rho(E_f) $$

$M$ is the amplitude for the process, which is based on fundamental physics coupling, it is not a function of environment.

The density of states, $\rho(E_f)$, describes the availability of final state decay products with energy $E_f$. It can be affected by environment; however, the environment usually has to be extreme, and the Earth's atmosphere is not extreme enough. An example is: a neutron star. The neutrons can't decay, because the final states are already occupied, and fermions can't occupy the same state.

I'll leave it as an open question whether there are conditions that are hot enough that time-dilation can slow the apparent decay rate. For a neutron decay, on would start to see relativistic effects around:

$$ KE = m_Nc^2 \approx kT $$

which is

$$ T = 12 \times 10^{12} K $$